# doctrine2 - querybuilder, empty parameters

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, query-builder

what can i do if the parameter has no value?

my query:

```
$query = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
                   ->select('u')
                   ->from('Users', 'u')
                   ->where('u.id = ?1')                   
                   ->andWhere('u.status= ?2')
                   ->setParameter(1, $userid)
                   ->setParameter(2, $status)
                   ->getQuery();

return $query->getResult();
```

if theres no $status,  then it doesnt display anything.

i tried putting a condition before the query to check if its null but what value can i set $status iif theres no status set

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The query builder is exactly there for building conditional queries. You could do:

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

$query = $qb->select('u')
            ->from('Users', 'u')
            ->where('u.id = ?1')                   
            ->setParameter(1, $userid);

if ($status) {
    $qb->andWhere('u.status = ?2')
       ->setParameter(2, $status);
}

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

On a side note, it is best practice to use named placeholders e. g. like this:

```
    $qb->andWhere('u.status = :status')
       ->setParameter('status', $status);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write:

```
->andWhere('(u.status= ?2 or ?2 is null)')
```

Comment: Clever solution but Max's answer is cleaner and more the OOP-Way. But +1 for cleverness anyway.

Comment: @Benjamin: Thanks. I'm more the SQL-kind of guy :-) But probably, the execution plan of Max's solution is better anyway