# Doctrine where if empty

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

```
 $repository = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('App\Entity\HolidayPackages');

$holiday_packages = $repository
            ->createQueryBuilder('hp')
            ->addSelect('hpt')
            ->innerJoin('hp.holiday_packages_translation', 'hpt')
            ->where('hpt.code = :code')
            ->setParameter('code', $language_code)
            ->andWhere('hpt.title LIKE :title')
            ->setParameter('title', $title . '%');

        if (!empty($starting_date)) {
            $repository
                ->andWhere('hp.starting_date = :starting_date')
                ->setParameter('starting_date', $starting_date);
        }

        $repository
            ->setFirstResult($offset)
            ->setMaxResults($limit)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

I am trying to filter search. How can i check if parameter is empty, don' t add to where query ?

I followed this link : [doctrine2 - querybuilder, empty parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389767/doctrine2-querybuilder-empty-parameters)

But i doesn't works for me.

When i try to like that, i got an error :

> Undefined method 'setFirstResult'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!

Thanks in advice..

**Update**

if i add to command line `setFirstResult` error change :

> Undefined method 'getQuery'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!

When i used to use pdo, i can like this using bind parameters. But i don't know how to do in Doctrine.

Comment: It is a pretty simple error.  Ask yourself what $holiday_packages = $repository->createQueryBuilder('hp') is doing and the problem will be obvious.

Comment: @Cerad can you tell me more about that pretty simple error pls ? I really can't unerstand what's the problem is

Comment: What @Cerad means is that you should use $holiday_packages instead of $repository in second and third blocks of code and your problem will be solved

Comment: @OlivierC thanks :)

Comment: The accepted answer should fix it, but maybe renaming $holiday_packages to something like $query_builder would make it more understandable for yourself in future. The first call createQueryBuilder returns a QueryBuilder object which is used in all the following calls. The reason the following calls work is because all the methods return $this (the QueryBuilder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep using `$holiday_packages` instead of `$repository`.

```
$repository = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('App\Entity\HolidayPackages');

$holiday_packages = $repository
                    ->createQueryBuilder('hp')
                    ->addSelect('hpt')
                    ->innerJoin('hp.holiday_packages_translation', 'hpt')
                    ->where('hpt.code = :code')
                    ->setParameter('code', $language_code)
                    ->andWhere('hpt.title LIKE :title')
                    ->setParameter('title', $title . '%');

if (!empty($starting_date)) {

     $holiday_packages->andWhere('hp.starting_date = :starting_date')
                      ->setParameter('starting_date', $starting_date);
}

$holiday_packages->setFirstResult($offset)
                 ->setMaxResults($limit)
                 ->getQuery()
                 ->getResult();
```